Is is possible to pass annotation class as a arguments to compose navigation?
Is is possible to pass this as an arguments to compose navigation?
Now I stil used navigation xml to change from page to another one
I would like to change to navigation compose but I am not sure that Is is possible?
@Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@StringDef(
   THB,
)
annotation class Currency {
    companion object {
        const val THB = "thb"
    }
}


How are you doing the same with XML Navigation?

I pass it as a string in XML navigation. I am going to change to compose navigation
